# Using Endpoints in an iOS Client: What is "output of ServiceGenerator"?

Tags: java, ios, xcode, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am following the instructions at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios to connect my iOS app to my app-engine endpoint. In subsection [Adding required files to your iOS project](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios#Java_Adding_required_files_to_your_iOS_project) at **step 3** I got stuck because I don't know what `also add the output of ServiceGenerator` means. Will someone who has done this before please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the output of ServiceGenerator following points 3,4 and 5 of [Compiling the client library generator and generating your library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios)

I'll try to explain how to do it and why:

before you can generate your iOS client library, you have to compile the tool that generates it, that's called *ServiceGenerator*.
To compile it, as said in the documentation, open the XCode project ServiceGenerator.xcodeproj and build the only target you have.
You'll use this tool from your terminal to generate your APIs, but for doing that you need an rpc-discovery [document](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis): a file containing some metadata that describes your APIs.

Here an example to generate a discovery rpc file from a terminal using the tool *endpoints.sh*

```
 $ {your_path_to_appengine_sdk}/endpoints.sh get-discovery-doc -f rpc your.package.yourAPIclass
```

Then you can generate your API client files with *ServiceGenerator*:

```
{your_ServiceGenerator_path) your_rpc_discovery_file.rpc --outputDir {your_output_directory}
```

And of course... now you have to include the files in your iOS project!